# Vim - mapping a key to a function which does something else plus the orginal function of that key

Tags: recursion, vim, keymapping

The target is to have the key <kbd>j</kbd> doing a possibly complex task **and** moving to the next line (the latter action performed just like the original function of the <kbd>j</kbd> key).

My initial attempt was to map <kbd>j</kbd> key this way:

```
nn j :<C-U>execute "call MyFun(" . v:count . ")"<CR>
```

(as you can see I intend to make <kbd>j</kbd>'s behavior depend on the count which is prepended to it)
and to define the function `MyFun` appropriately:

```
fu! MyFun(count)
  " do more stuff based on a:count
  normal j
endf
```

which is faulty, as hitting <kbd>j</kbd> now results in the error `E169: Command too recursive`, since the non-recursivity of `nnoremap`, as long as my deduction is correct, applies to the "literal" content of the `{rhs}` of the mapping, and not to whatever is "inside" it (in other words the `function` body makes use of the meaning of <kbd>j</kbd> at the moment it is called, thus causing the infinte recursion).

Therefore I tried the following

```
nn , j
nn j :<C-U>execute "call MyFun(" . v:count . ")"<CR>
fu! MyFun(count)
  " do more stuff based on a:count
  normal ,
endf
```

However this means that I waste the key <kbd>,</kbd>. I know I can avoid the waste of that mapping doing

```
nn <Plug>Nobody j
```

but then I wouldn't know how to use `<Plug>Nobody` (my understanding is indeed that its use is only in the `{rhs}` of another, non-`nore` mapping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My initial attempt was to map j key this way

Using `execute` here is redundant. It's enough to do:

```
nnoremap j :<C-U>call MyFun(v:count)<CR>
```

> now results in the error E169: Command too recursive

That's because of `normal`. To suppress remapping you must use "bang"-form: `normal! j`. Please, refere
 to documentation for `:normal`, whose second paragraph describes exactly your use case:

> If the `[!]` is given, mappings will not be used. Without it, when this
>   command is called from a non-remappable mapping (`:noremap`), the
>   argument can be mapped anyway.

Besides, note that `j` normally supports count, so `2j` is expected to move two lines down. So you, probably, should do `execute 'normal!' a:count . 'j'` instead.

Comment: `execute` is just a remnant of some previous more complicated attempt, but thank you.